# What is the yellow bag with black letters on the back of Dade's door?

Tags: hackers

In the movie Hackers, in at least one scene in Dade's bedroom (when The Plague is threatening him) you can see a yellow bag (possibly a laundry bag) with some black writing and a logo on it hanging on the back of his door. Many of the objects in the environment in this movie are nods to the early to mid 90's hacker culture, and I am curious if this object is one of them, but can't make out enough of the lettering to find out exactly what it is. It looks like it might say "Carcass Covers" along with some more writing at the top but searches for this phrase understandably don't yield any relevant results.

What is this bag? What is the relevance to the culture celebrated by this movie?

[image: Wider view of bag with fewer letters visible]

[image: Closer view of bag with more letters visible]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it's a clothing brand because I found [this](https://www.grailed.com/listings/26590626-streetwear-x-very-rare-x-vintage-vintage-brand-streetwear-carcass-covers-nyc-sweatshirt-1990s).

[image]

So that yellow bag might be clothing bag for carrying clothes for dry cleaning.
It appears that this brand dates back to 1990's.

Comment: Nice find! That definitely looks like it matches.